# catkin lib variable for catkin_make and catkin_make_isolated

Tags: ros, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have two catkin packages, one generating a library and the other makes use of it. In the cmake file of the dependent project, I have "link_directories(  ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/lib/ )". This works fine with catkin_make, as the libxxx.so gets generated in devel/lib/. However when using catkin_make_isolated, the libxxx.so gets generated in devel_isolated/project_xxx/lib/ instead. And ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX} does not seem to dynamically substitute with the correct path according to the catkin command used. What cmake or catkin variable should I use for the link_directories to work in both cases?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239873/catkin-lib-variable-for-catkin_make-and-catkin_make_isolated/) by [blueberry](https://answers.ros.org/users/26696/blueberry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not use `link_directories` at all.

In the package where you create the library:

- export the library and the headers in the `catkin_package` call
- install the library and the headers

in the package where you use it:

- `find_pacakge` the pacakge above
- use `target_link_libraries(TARGET ${catkin_LIBRARIES}) and` include_directores(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})`

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous29979](https://answers.ros.org/users/29979/anonymous29979/) on 2018-09-07**:
For an explanation on why this works, read http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Why_Are_Catkin_Packages_Specified_as_Components.3F